# How to detect dos format files in git bash

Tags: bash, grep, newlines

Git Bash is a nice bash shell you get in Windows as part of the installation of Git. It comes with other typical unix tools bundled inside, such as grep, sed, awk, perl. It doesn't have the file command.

In this shell, I want to detect files that have DOS-style line endings. I thought this command would work but it doesn't:

```
grep -l ^M$ *
```

It doesn't work, even files that don't have CR line endings match. For example if I create 2 sample files `hello.unix` and `hello.dos`, I can confirm with `wc` that `hello.unix` has 6 characters and `hello.dos` has 7 characters because of the extra CR, but both files match with `grep`. That is:

```
$ cat hello.*
hello
hello

$ wc hello.*
      1       1       7 hello.dos
      1       1       6 hello.unix
      2       2      13 total

$ grep -l ^M hello.*
hello.dos
hello.unix
```

Is this a bug in the implementation of `grep` in Git Bash? 
Is there another way to find all files with DOS-style line endings?

Comment: I don't know what Git bash is, does it have the 'file' command?

Comment: Are you aware of `git config core.autocrlf input`?

Comment: May I wonder why xargs and not just use the exec option of find? Doesn't it exist in git bash?

Comment: @DavidKohen you're right, `-exec` would work too. But it's irrelevant for the question, so I removed that now.

Comment: @cjm This is not necessarily for files under version control but any files

Comment: You need to quote: "^M". And create the ^M by typing <ctrl>+V<ctrl>+M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sch has lead me to this solution:

```
sed -bne '/\r$/ {p;q}' < /path/to/file | grep -q .
```

This exits with TRUE if the file has any lines ending with CR. To hook this into find:

```
find /path/to/ -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -bne "/\r$/ {p;q}" < "$1" | grep -q .' sh {} \; -print
```

And I think I know why `grep -l ^M hello.*` doesn't work in this shell: it seems that in Git Bash `^M` characters are removed from all command line arguments, so `grep` never actually receives the character, and therefore all files match. This behavior is not only on the command line, but in shell scripts too.

So the key is to express the `^M` character with other symbols, such as `\r`, instead of literally.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Silly me. Of course ^M is CR; and your command should work (works on my system). However, you need to type Ctrl-V Ctrl-M to get the literal '\r'/CR (and not two characters, `^` and `M`).

Alternatives:

Do this:

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l `printf '\r\n'`
```

Or this:

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lP '\r\n'
```

You can also use the file utility (not sure if it comes with GIT bash):

```
find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep CRLF
```

Comment: Yeah it should normally work, but it does not work in Git Bash. Unfortunately none of your tips work: the `printf` doesn't work, `grep` doesn't have `-P` flag, and there is no `file` command in Git Bash... Any other ideas?

Comment: How about `\`echo -e '\r\n'\``? Should do the same as printf.

Comment: Same as `printf`, none of the files match that way.

Comment: Um, so most likely a bug. Do you have a C compiler installed? I can write you a little C program that should work.

Comment: No gcc or cc comes with Git Bash. I don't want to install cygwin. So, thanks, but nevermind. My workaround is to convert all files which I *suspect* to have CR line-endings. The files which don't have will not be changed so it should be ok, it's just an ugly solution.

Comment: The C program does not have to be compiled by Cygwin, it can be compiled for Windows using any other C compiler (like VS Express).

Comment: Thanks @DavidKohen but I'd rather install cygwin than VS* ;-)

Comment: I just thought of another thing. Do you have `sed`? Could you try `sed -n '/\r$/p'`? Does it show a different result for the CRLF terminated files?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about git bash, but maybe

```
if [ "$(tr -cd '\r' < file | wc -c)" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo there are CR characters in there
fi
```

would work. The idea being not to use *text* utilities that may treat the CR and LF characters specially.

If that doesn't work, then maybe

```
if od -An -tx1 < file | grep -q 0d; then
  echo there are CR characters in there
fi
```

To hook into find:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'od -An -tx1 < "$1" | grep -q 0d' sh {} \; -print
```

Comment: No `od` in Git Bash. But the `tr` trick is pretty clever and it works! There is just one relatively minor issue with it: it detects CR anywhere in the file, but I need to detect CR at line endings. You have lead me to the solution, using `sed` instead of `tr`. See my answer for more details, and thanks again!

Comment: When is CR used outside of line endings?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Python:

```
import string
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    if (string.find(line,"\r")!=-1):
        print fileinput.filename()
        fileinput.nextfile()
```

This small python file would behave just like you would expect the grep (get a filename list and print the names with CR in them).

Answer (score 0):

Use the file  command on Linux/Ubuntu. If the file is in DOS format, the output will include the words, "with CRLF line terminators". If the file is in UNIX format, no such words will be in the output. In the example, below, del.txt is in DOS format and del is in UNIX format.

```
$ file del.txt
del.txt: C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ echo "hello" > del
user@decatur2:~/manpuriav$ file del
del: ASCII text
```