# How to grep for windows and mac EOLs?

Tags: grep

I have a directory with *.txt files.

How can I list the txt filenames that are still having non-unix eol's? So windows and mac eols.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/73886/7156944)

Answer (score 2):

"mac eols" (carriage returns) are rare since around 2000 (i.e., since OSX was first released).  For finding files with CRLF endings, the `file` utility is helpful, since it is looking at more than `grep` might.

Further reading

- [How to test whether a file uses CRLF or LF without modifying it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79702/how-to-test-whether-a-file-uses-crlf-or-lf-without-modifying-it/79707#79707)
- [How to detect dos format files in git bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50565/how-to-detect-dos-format-files-in-git-bash/50566#50566)
- [How do you search for files containing dos line endings (CRLF) with grep on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833/how-do-you-search-for-files-containing-dos-line-endings-crlf-with-grep-on-linu/73886#73886)
- [An Illustrated History of macOS](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/history-of-macos)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "file" command. When a file is using CRLF EOL, "file" returned

**filename: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators**

for UNIX EOL, it returns:

**filename: ASCII text**